# NPM errors while creating a new sails project by the command : sails new test-project

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, npm-scripts

I am very new to sails js. I just installed sails globally on my local machine and when I try to create a new project with the command "sails new test-project", it just fails. And it fails every time, the error is somewhere with NPM.

Following is the verbose from the command prompt.

```
Failed to install dependencies.
New app was generated successfully, but some dependencies 
in node_modules/ are probably still incomplete or missing.

Before you continue, please make sure you are connected to the
internet, and that your NPM registry hasn't gone down.
Then cd into the new app and run:
    rm -rf node_modules && npm install

See below for complete error details.
For more help, visit https://sailsjs.com/support.

error: { 

Error: Command failed: npm install
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@2.1.0: This project is unmaintained

npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.10.0: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to
  "coffeescript" (no hyphen)

npm WARN deprecated buildmail@2.0.0: This project is unmaintained

npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading
  Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.

npm WARN deprecated sprintf@0.1.5: The sprintf package is deprecated in
  favor of sprintf-js.

npm WARN deprecated uws@9.14.0: stop using this version

npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.10: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at
  least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and
  an import issue introduced in 2.1.0

npm WARN notice [SECURITY] lodash has the following vulnerability:
1 low. Go here for more details:
  https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=lodash&version=3.10.1 
  - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and
    then `npm audit` to get more info.

npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
  'E:\workspace\matallica\backenD\node_modules\.staging\sails-generate-5ef564b7\lib\builtins\copy\index.js'

npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
  'E:\workspace\matallica\backenD\node_modules\.staging\statuses-8d66e757\index.js'

npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
  'E:\workspace\matallica\backenD\node_modules\.staging\statuses-8d66e757\HISTORY.md'

npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
  'E:\workspace\matallica\backenD\node_modules\.staging\statuses-8d66e757\codes.json'

npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. 

You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY

npm ERR! sha512-wGUIVQXuehL5TCqQun8OW81jGzAWycqzFF8lFp+GOM5BXLYj3bKNsYC4daB7n6XjCqxQA/qgTJ+8ANR3acjrog== 
  integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-wGUIVQXuehL5TCqQun8OW81jGzAWycqzFF8lFp+GOM5BXLYj3bKNsYC4daB7n6XjCqxQA/qgTJ+8ANR3acjrog== 
  but got sha512-tuJp5MrQL1Q4DGVO5CQN6FghjuWqnA6mURYP+s8UFEV3ezesOPSE3F9F/47+dLvOXPfulVuk729nHGYpVaS1ag==. (742 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-29T08_32_47_710Z-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:557:12) killed:
        false, code: 1, signal: null, cmd: 'npm install' }
```

Comment: It looks like npm was either down of blocked inside your network.

Comment: How it can be verified ? I can access https://www.npmjs.com/ and npm install works for other projects aw well.

Answer (score 0):

Delete package-lock.json `rm package-lock.json` and node_modules `rm -rf node_modules`

Try the following commands:

```
npm cache clean

sudo npm install
```

And now Try your command:

```
sails new test-project
```

Comment: Welcome!! Please accept the answer, so that this question is closed. :)